# Monaca Localkit Launch Error

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

When I try to launch the Monaca Localkit application, it shows "Unable to start HTTP server. Maybe the port is occupied. Please change the port and restart the program."

Then, I have changed my port setting many times, but it still shows the same message.

My default port setting is 8001. And I checked whether other application is using this port by netstat command. But no application is using.

I tried to re-install Monaca Localkit application too. But the result is the same as before.

How can I fix this problem? Please give me an advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that another program is using that port, maybe another instance of localkit? If yes, terminate the program to free the port. You should also check if your firewall allows communications through port 8001.

If you want just to change port, you can open Localkit and go, from the menu bar, to `Monaca Localkit -> Preferences` and change `Listening Port`.

Comment: @KazzzStudio Glad you were able to solved it. If my answer helped you, please consider to upvote it and mark it as correct answer so the users with the same issue can easily find it :)

Comment: Thanks for your kindness support. As you said, another instance had running on my machine. I had terminated 'monaca livesync' command by typing ctrl+z instead of ctrl+c. I didn't know ctrl+z command doesn't terminate monaca process. Because of you, I could solve the problem. But I couldn't upvoted your answer because my reputation is not enough to upvote it. It sems that I have to earn 15 reputation to upvote it.  Because of my poor English, if I have been misunderstanding, please give me an advise.